# A SpringBoard alert is blocking test execution - Xamarin UITest C#

Tags: visual-studio-app-center, xamarin.uitest

I encountered the following problem on ios. When I launch the app with UITest from xamarin, ios will present a springboard alert. It is asking me if the app is allowed to send messages.

Anyone a clue on how to accept these alerts?

The complete stacktrace:

```
  at UniversalApp.UITests.Utils.User.TapCoordinates (System.Single x, System.Single y, System.String description) [0x00006] in <f9fcfaf13de2474da4249e746e944d83>:0   at UniversalApp.UITests.Pages.PushNotifications.ApproveMessageNotification.AllowNotificationBeingPushed () [0x00007] in <f9fcfaf13de2474da4249e746e944d83>:0   at UniversalApp.UITests.Tests.BaseTest.TapAllowNotifications () [0x00014] in <f9fcfaf13de2474da4249e746e944d83>:0   at UniversalApp.UITests.Tests.BaseTest.Login () [0x00001] in <f9fcfaf13de2474da4249e746e944d83>:0   at UniversalApp.UITests.Tests.BaseTest.BeforeEachTest () [0x0000f] in <f9fcfaf13de2474da4249e746e944d83>:0   at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00032] in <48b95f3df5804531818f80e28ec60191>:0 --AggregateException  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional (System.Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) [0x00011] in <48b95f3df5804531818f80e28ec60191>:0   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait (System.Int32 millisecondsTimeout, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00043] in <48b95f3df5804531818f80e28ec60191>:0   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait () [0x00000] in <48b95f3df5804531818f80e28ec60191>:0   at Xamarin.UITest.iOS.iOSGestures.TapCoordinates (System.Single x, System.Single y) [0x00020] in <18ae7883e2424c558186d1d9edf9f14b>:0   at Xamarin.UITest.iOS.iOSApp+<>c__DisplayClass31_0.<TapCoordinates>b__0 () [0x0005e] in <18ae7883e2424c558186d1d9edf9f14b>:0   at Xamarin.UITest.Utils.ErrorReporting.With (System.Action func, System.Object[] args, System.String memberName) [0x00006] in <18ae7883e2424c558186d1d9edf9f14b>:0 --DeviceAgentException  at Xamarin.UITest.XDB.Services.iOSDeviceAgentService+DeviceAgentResult.Validate (System.String action) [0x00023] in <18ae7883e2424c558186d1d9edf9f14b>:0   at Xamarin.UITest.XDB.Services.iOSDeviceAgentService+<RequestAsync>d__34`1[T].MoveNext () [0x00104] in <18ae7883e2424c558186d1d9edf9f14b>:0 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <48b95f3df5804531818f80e28ec60191>:0   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <48b95f3df5804531818f80e28ec60191>:0   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <48b95f3df5804531818f80e28ec60191>:0   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <48b95f3df5804531818f80e28ec60191>:0   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <48b95f3df5804531818f80e28ec60191>:0   at Xamarin.UITest.XDB.Services.iOSDeviceAgentService+<GestureAsync>d__16.MoveNext () [0x000cd] in <18ae7883e2424c558186d1d9edf9f14b>:0 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <48b95f3df5804531818f80e28ec60191>:0   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <48b95f3df5804531818f80e28ec60191>:0   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <48b95f3df5804531818f80e28ec60191>:0   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <48b95f3df5804531818f80e28ec60191>:0   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in <48b95f3df5804531818f80e28ec60191>:0   at Xamarin.UITest.XDB.Services.iOSDeviceAgentService+<PointGestureAsync>d__35.MoveNext () [0x000a0] in <18ae7883e2424c558186d1d9edf9f14b>:0 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <48b95f3df5804531818f80e28ec60191>:0   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <48b95f3df5804531818f80e28ec60191>:0   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <48b95f3df5804531818f80e28ec60191>:0   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <48b95f3df5804531818f80e28ec60191>:0   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in <48b95f3df5804531818f80e28ec60191>:0   at Xamarin.UITest.XDB.Services.iOSDeviceAgentService+<TouchAsync>d__29.MoveNext () [0x0007d] in <18ae7883e2424c558186d1d9edf9f14b>:0
```

Answer (score 1):

We use DeviceAgent in UITest which should accept notifications automatically.

I would check that the text on your alert matches the [DeviceAgent source code](https://github.com/calabash/DeviceAgent.iOS/blob/b6ac427308ed5b4a58ddc7011d04ccc13754f707/Server/Utilities/SpringBoardAlerts.m#L107)

It may be that the text isn't matched against any of the examples in DeviceAgent - in which case a new entry will need to be added to the above file and a new version of DeviceAgent released to handle this.

You can also [read more about this in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ios-privacy-alerts#xamarinuitest-and-calabash-ios)

I would advise reaching out to App Center support in the appcenter.ms portal for further assistance.

Comment: Looks like Springboard alert dismissal is broken. Probably because apple changed the way (at least in my case) Location Alert is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

I worked around this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter/issues/2060) by calling `DismissSpringboardAlerts` for my iOS UI tests:

```
(App as Xamarin.UITest.iOS.iOSApp).DismissSpringboardAlerts();
```